# Why repeated and map in GRPC have no public setters?

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

In C# generated from `proto` files, why aren't there a public setter?

MSFT documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-8.0#lists) mentions that: "RepeatedField properties don't have a public setter. Items should be added to the existing collection."

The same goes for dictionaries: "Like repeated properties, map properties don't have a public setter. Items should be added to the existing collection."

What is the reason for this decision?

Comment: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6995#issuecomment-1134875113

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. Basically, they wanted to keep the reference to collections/maps immutable.